# Identificar Erro do parse no Adroid Studio

Tags: android, parse

Como identificar o erro  através do código retornado pelo parse?

[image: Erro parse]

Comment: Olhando na tabela de erros da API ou interface que está usando, pelo código correspondente.

Comment: Olhando a documentação também ajuda, após seguir a dica do Bacco

Answer (score 0):

Voce encontra no [http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/](http://site)
a tabela com o código e a descrição referente de cada erro.